# Finding files contained in particular block group

Tags: files, filesystems, ext3, debugfs

How do I see/list what files have blocks in a particular block group? I'm looking at a small disk image with an `ext3` file system. Can I use `debugfs`, and if so, how?

Comment: related/possible duplicate [How to list files that occupy a block group?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90464)